# Regex match pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to count the amount of times I use \n\n\n (3 linebreaks) after some text. It counts almost as I like, the problem is when you spam newlines that will be counted which I don't want to.

Edit: Seems like the regex from regexr does not support .net so I have to come up with a pattern that works with .net.

Example for the text that the regex will check on:

> Description for something
>
> text \n \n \n // this will make DescriptionAmount++
>
> Description for something
>
> text\n \n \n // this will make DescriptionAmount++
>
> \n \n \n  // this shouldn't add on DescriptionAmount

Here's the code I've done so far.

```
int DescriptionAmount = Regex.Matches(somestring, "[^\w$](\r\n){2}[^\w$]").Count;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure you capture the 3 linebreaks after some text would take something like:

```
\w+\s*\n{3}
```

Since this is .net, you either need to put an @ in front:

```
@"\w+\s*\n{3}
```

or escape the slashes like:

```
"\\w+\\s\n{3}
```

You mentioned that you are searching for three `\n`, but your search has `\r\n`. If you are looking for `\r\n` instead, just add `\r` in front of the `\n` and surround with () for `(\\r\\n)` or `(\r\n)` in the expressions above.

One other thing, depending on the text in some string, you may want to apply the multiline option like:

```
Regex.Matches(somestring, "\\w\\s\n{3}", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: thanks, modified so it would look like @"\w+\s*(\r\n){3}" \r\n must be together () must be added.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a quantifier {x,y} to select how many tokens you want to match.

The '*' will match the preceding character 0 or many times, meaning it will match any \n after the 3rd token.

\n{3} says \n must be matched 3 times no more no less.

I find this tool http://regexr.com/ very useful for building and debugging regex statements.

Comment: Thanks for a better regex pattern, the weird part is that I get 0 counts now and I use that site. The pattern matches with multiple newlines after the text too...

Comment: Do not use regexr when you test .net regexps, it does not support its syntax.

Comment: Then what do you suggest then? That can be the reason that I just get 0 in count, that the syntax is wrong indeed.